# How to perform routing for list/detail components in dashboard

Tags: angular, angular-routing, dashboard

My dashboard is a 3 column layout with list components displayed in all three columns. When user clicks an item on a specific list I'd like to replace the respective list with a detail component. The other 2 list components should be left unchanged. Is this doable? Appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Currently, my entire dashboard is replaced by the detail component when any list items are clicked.

Comment: Use nested routers. https://blog.devgenius.io/the-art-of-nested-router-outlets-in-angular-dafb38245a30

Comment: Or named outlets: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets